# Object inheritance - example of TransformerMixin from sklearn.base

Tags: python, inheritance, scikit-learn

I am trying to understand definition of the class TransformerMixin from here [GitHub link](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765a/sklearn/base.py#L428)

At the very end of class definition there is a line:

```
self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
```

Class TransformerMixin does not define method `fit` or `transform`, but since it inherits from `object`, I assume that `object` class defines method `fit`, but I cannot find it. Any suggestions?

Comment: No, there is no `.fit` on `object`. Presumably `TransformerMixin` is meant to be mixed in with classes that *do* define it.

Comment: Ok, thank you! It makes sense.